# How to add TextMate to my PATH on Mac?

Tags: macos, textmate

When you start using TextMate, you are instructed to create an alias for mate='open -a TextMate.app'. But now I am using another program that requires me to add it to the PATH. I'm not sure how to do it though. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My TextMate installation includes *Terminal Usage...* item in the *Help* menu, that allows me to install a symlink in a directory of my choice, the default being `/usr/local/bin`. This seems to be the preferred way to do this, as it is accessible from within TextMate itself.

In TextMate2, the option is located under *TextMate » Preferences… » Terminal*.

Answer (score 6):

`mate` is actually a utility that comes with TextMate. It is located at `/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/mate`. The easiest way to add it to your path is to create a symlink to it:

```
ln -s /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/mate ~/bin/mate
```

Then add `~/bin` to your path by adding the following line in your `~/.profile`:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

More details can be found in the [TextMate Manual](http://manual.macromates.com/en/using_textmate_from_terminal.html). Info such as this:

> Mac OS X comes with an open shell command which can be used to simulate a double click from within Terminal. It can also perform an *Open With…* operation by use of the `-a` argument, e.g.: `open -a TextMate .` will open the current folder in TextMate (as a scratch project).
>
> This standard command has a few shortcomings: it can only open one file at a time, it cannot open a document at a specific line and it cannot “stall” the shell until the file has been closed, which is useful e.g. when using an editor to write something like a subversion commit message.
>
> For this reason TextMate comes with its own mate shell command, which supersedes the open command. For usage instructions you can run `mate -h` (from Terminal).

Answer (score 1):

you can add to your path in osx with the following command:

```
echo 'export PATH=YOURPATHHERE:$PATH' >> ~/.profile, replacing "YOURPATHHERE"
```

obviously replacing 'YOURPATHHERE' with the path you need. This will add it to your profile so that every time you log it is set.

Comment: There's more needed here specifically for `mate`. See my post.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check out the TextMate wiki: http://wiki.macromates.com/Troubleshooting/TextMateAndThePath

Comment: This is to change the PATH that is accessible to TextMate, *not* about how to put TextMate or `mate` in your PATH.